# Why can't a windows service created in C# detect that a screen saver is currently running?

Tags: c#, service, screensaver

As part of some work I need to get done for Windows 10, I have written a code in C# that essentially detects every minute whether a PC is in screen saver mode or not, and it writes to a table in MySQL the relevant status ("PC in use" if the screen saver is off, "available PC" if the screen saver is on).

I did this using (full link if required - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17067/Controlling-The-Screen-Saver-With-C):

// Returns TRUE if the screen saver is actually running
   public static bool GetScreenSaverRunning( )
   {
      bool isRunning = false;

```
  SystemParametersInfo( SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, 
     ref isRunning, 0 );
  return isRunning;
```

}

The code works flawlessly in console application mode (I made a loop to test it out over a minute with a check up on screen save status every 10 seconds), this means in MySQL the status was set correctly every time, depending on the screen save status at the moment of the check up.

The problem occurs when I use this code for a windows service. The service is installed correctly, the log on tab is set on Local System (I also tried with the logged in user instead, same results) and I allow the service to interact with the desktop, just in case, but the difference here is that no matter if the PC enters screen save or not, it always returns false on GetScreenSaverRunning(), thus setting the status of the PC in MySQL as "PC in use", even if the screen saver is on at the moment of check up.

I get the sense that the problem isn't in the code itself, since it works without any issues as a console application, but perhaps something behind the scenes. I tried to search here and on many other websites, haven't found anything related to such a problem.

Does anyone have any idea at all what might be the issue? Any help and/or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

(I could post the code if required, but it is pretty much straight forward and the main part of it, controlling the screen save detection, is taken from the website mentioned above, afterwards it's a simple if (GetScreenSaverRunning() == true) )

Comment: i'd go with Christophers Solution. If you want to do it with a service: Services run in Session 0, Session 0 doesnt have a desktop or a Screensaver. So from your service you have to create a process in Session 1,2,3... whatever session the user[s] are runnning in. Then your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

Ever since Vista, [Services are barred from a Interactive Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services). Even if they run under the same rights, they do not get a interactive Session. I would guess that is getting in the way here.

While you can overwrite this behavior in the Service settings, this is not adviseable for new code. Consider making this a Background Task started by the Task Sheduler instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because the windows service runs in different session then the windows logon. You can't interact with the desktop related services unless you run the windows service in win logon session. There used to be an option in Windows service manager where you can set the properties to "Interact with desktop session" but I don't think that ever worked.

There's a work around to run the windows service using the win logo session.
See this helper class that can get the current logged on user session and interact with the desktop services. https://github.com/murrayju/CreateProcessAsUser/blob/master/ProcessExtensions/ProcessExtensions.cs